# Whats the best way to check if a custom attribute exists in Magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection, custom

In being careful, I want to check if my custom attribute exists before I attempt to utilize it in any way.  I need to check against all attributes collection, not just the product collection.   My attribute may exist on a customer, a product, or on a custom model of my own creation.

In magento 1.x, I'd use the following:

```
$attr = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter('specialty')->getFirstItem();

if ($attr->getAttributeId() > 0) {
 Do some stuff....'
```

I can't find anything that explicitly does something like this

Comment: Try this it may be help you http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-display-brand-value-in-product-detail-page/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need use `\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface::get` method for this.

For example:

```
try {

   $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get($entityType, $attributeCode);

} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {

    //  attribute does not exist

}
```

Comment: Hi Kandy , how to check the custom attribute assigned or not for the product?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface` to determine the product attribute

```
    try {
            $this->attributeRepository->get('custom_attribute');
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

            //To-do create attribute
        }
```

This is verified on 2.3.2