# How to check if custom product attribute exists

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I want to check if my custom product attributes exist before I attempt to utilize it in any way. Whats the best way to check it in Magento 2.

Note that I don't want to check if specific product has the attribute. I want to check **if that attribute exists** in Magento.

I've found partial answer on stackexchange https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107993/14809

but that answer is very limited. Especially the code example is very scarce:

```
try {
   $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get($entityType, $attributeCode);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    //  attribute is not exists
}
```

1. It's not clear what to enter in `$entityType`.
2. What will `get` return if the attribute does not exist?
3. I don't know where to find example implementation of the methods (e.g. `get(...)`) defined in the interface \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `$entityType` in your case is the `'catalog_product'` as its a product attribute
2. It will throw an exception
3. `vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/AttributeRepository.php` and check the public function `get($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode)`

Comment: Important note to **2**: If the attribute doesn't exists a `NoSuchEntityException` is thrown **and** Magento creates the attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You can inject `Magento\Eav\Model\Config` object and use the `getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributecode)` function to check if your custom eav attribute with code `$attributecode` already exist or not.

Here is the code sample:

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode);
if (!$attribute || !$attribute->getAttributeId()) {
    throw new NoSuchEntityException(
        __('Attribute with attributeCode "%1" does not exist.', $attributeCode)
    );
}
return $attribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "eav_entity_type" table. It will show you all the attribute type code you can use while fetching the information.